# Allow custom events on main form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, class, events

Let's say I have class foo:

```
Public Class foo
End Class
```

Now let's say I have a function that is called externally:

```
Public Class foo
  Public Sub my_sub ()
  End Sub
End Class
```

What if, some of the time, I want other functions to be able to know when this function is called and certain conditions are met? No problem, I'll create an event:

```
Public Class foo
  Event something_happened ()
  Public Sub my_sub ()
    If some_condition_is_met Then
      RaiseEvent something_happened ()
    Else
     'Do Nothing!
   End If
 End Sub
```

End Class

Now, when I create an instance of the class i have to declare it as so:

```
Dim WithEvents my_foo As foo
```

Well, when I create my own events in a form class for other classes to receive, VB complains because the instance of the form is not declared as:

```
WithEvents
```

How can I make the form support the addition of events that can be received with other applications, considering I do not declare an instance in my code so cannot insert:

```
With Events
```

Do I change the auto generated code that does declare it or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment I think I got what you meant. Please take a look at this:

```
Public Class DesignerForm
    Public Event YourEvent()

    Private LC As ListenerClass

    Private Sub YourMethod()
        If True Then 'Your conditionals go here.
            RaiseEvent YourEvent()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DesignerForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LC = New ListenerClass(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        YourMethod()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ListenerClass
    Private WithEvents DF As DesignerForm

    Public Sub New(ByRef DF As DesignerForm)
        Me.DF = DF
    End Sub

    Private Sub YourEventExternalHandler() Handles DF.YourEvent
        'Here you handle YourEvent outside your Main Form Class.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Your main form class is directly generated by the WFD and your class takes a reference to its run-time instance. In this example, when you click Button1 YourEvent is fired and handled in ListenerClass.

P.S.
All of this stands only if you can have at least some kind of visibility of DesignerForm class from ListenerClass (any kind of: project reference, dynamic loading, and so on), otherwise you cannot even refer to it and you will have to go with the common interprocess communication mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The `WithEvents` keyword does not magically mean that an object will raise events or other objects can handle them.  The `WithEvents` keyword specifically means that a variable can be used in a `Handles` clause.  That's it.

If an object raises events then it raises events.  If you want to handle those events and that object is not assigned to a variable that is declared `WithEvents` then you use an `AddHandler` statement to register a method as a handler for an event.  You then use `RemoveHandler` when you don't want to handle the event any longer.

Note that, while the syntax is slightly different, this is the one and only way to handle events in C#; there is no equivalent to `WithEvents` and `Handles`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question, but, how about this (very simplified) example?

```
Public Class YourForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Public Event E1()

    ' In this example event may be fired on form loading.
    Public Sub YourForm_Load() Handles MyBase.Load 
        If True Then ' You may use your conditionals here.
            RaiseEvent E1()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class AnotherForm
    ' You may not need to inherit from Form
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Dim WithEvents F1 As YourForm

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        F1 = New YourForm()
    End Sub

    Public Sub YourFormLoadingHandler() Handles F1.E1
        'Handle your event here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Whenever YourForm is set for loading by AnotherForm, you have the chance to handle the event in the second class.

Again I may have not understood the question.

Regards.

Comment: My question mainly relates to the fact that visual basic WILL NOT allow the handling of events belonging to an instance of an object if the instance was not declared with the keyword 'WithEvents'. If my designer form, that I make using the visual studio designer, needs to have events for an custom class to receive, how can I allow this considering that VB requires objects that have events that are handled  to be declared with a keyword? I don't declare a designer form so I can't add the keyword but I need the object to have useable events. I don't really understand your answer.

Comment: Nevermind, with this comment I better understood your question. Please hold on while I format the answer.